# How to use std::nested_exception and friends?

Tags: c++, exception

I've noticed that there are a few more interesting declarations in `<exception>` in C++11. Can anybody shed any light on what they mean and how to use them?

The ones I'm wondering about are:

1. `::std::nested_exception`
2. `::std::throw_with_nested`
3. `::std::rethrow_if_nested`

Additionally, while they seem self-explanatory, it might be nice to know how these worked:

1. `::std::exception_ptr`
2. `::std::make_exception_ptr`
3. `::std::current_exception`
4. `::std::rethrow_exception`

Comment: A good (the best?) description is available in the standard. You can read the last [publicly available draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) for free.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some high level code will generically just catch `std::exception` and print the `what()`. You want to squeeze as much information as possible to this generic mechanism, yet without losing any information. Consider an implementation of some archive library:

```
archive::archive(const char* filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    file.exceptions(ios_base::badbit);
    open_archive(file); // throws ios_base::failure, or some other low-level exception.
}
```

The information available to the archive is not recorded (e.g. filename). Besides you would like to distinguish exceptions that came from the archive class from other exceptions.

```
archive::archive(const char* filename)
{
    try {
        ifstream file(filename);
        file.exceptions(ios_base::badbit);
        open_archive(file); // throws ios_base::failure, or some other low-level exception.
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        throw archive_exception("Can't open archive", filename, e.what());
    }
}
```

Now we added higher-level semantic information that `archive` class knows, but we also lost the information about the original cause of problem (the type of `e`). `nested_exception` is meant to solve this problem:

```
archive::archive(const char* filename)
{
    try {
        ifstream file(filename);
        file.exceptions(ios_base::badbit);
        open_archive(file); // throws ios_base::failure, or some other low-level exception.
    } catch(...) {
        throw_with_nested(archive_exception("Can't open archive", filename));
    }
}
```

All the available information is recorded. We can now generically retrieve it in the catch site:

```
void print_exception_info(const std::exception& e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    try {
        rethrow_if_nested(e);
    } catch(const std::exception& ne) {
        print_exception_info(ne);
    } catch(...) { }
}

int main() {
    try {
        run();
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        print_exception_info(e);
    }
}
```

The output will be more descriptive than before. It will describe the problem starting from the high-level to the low-level:

> Can't open archive "my_archive.bin"
>
> Access is denied.

Or perhaps:

> Can't open archive "my_archive.bin"
>
> Record 'aabb' not found.

The functions working with `exception_ptr` are designed to transfer exceptions between threads, or more generally, store an exception for later use. How they work depends on the implementation. The intention was that `exception_ptr` will be a shared pointer to the exception object. However when this pointer is created, when throwing the exception or when trying to get an `exception_ptr` to it, is subject to the implementation. The implementation is still free to copy the exception when you call `current_exception()`.

Comment: Wouldn't `print_exception_info` look better as something like `try { std::rethrow_if_nested(); } catch...`?

Comment: I have generally been reserving places to stuff the low level exception in my high level exceptions when I want to do this. But I can see how this generic mechanism is better since you can have a very generic handler that unwraps it all.

Comment: I borrowed much of your example for [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/nested_exception) - feel free to edit that wiki if you wish to remove or improve it.

Comment: In case anyone wants to use this with GCC, keep in mind [bug 51438](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51438)

Comment: @Cubbi: Yeah, that's pretty irritating. I noticed it too and wondered if anybody had already filed a bug report.